# Why doesn't my bit minipulation construct work in C

Tags: c

What I'm trying to do is make a mask with a 1 bit all the way to the left side of the set of bits with the rest being zero, irrespective of variable size. I tried the following:

```
unsigned char x = ~(~0 >> 1);
```

which, to me, should work whether it's done on a char or an int, but it doesn't!

To me, the manipulation looks like this:

```
||||||||
0|||||||
|0000000
```

This is what it appears it should look like, and on a 16-bit integer:

```
|||||||| ||||||||
0||||||| ||||||||
|0000000 00000000
```

Why doesn't this construct work? It's giving me zero whether I try to assign it to an unsigned char, or an int.

I'm on like 50 page of K&R, so I'm pretty new. I don't know what a literal means, I'm not sure what an "arithmetic" shift is, I don't know how to use suffix', and I damn sure can't use a structure.

Comment: You know those literals you're shifting are ints?

Comment: you need to cast to a unsigned type before shifting. a signed type uses arithmetic shift right which duplicates the sign bit (top bit). use the unsigned type that is as big as you need. use `~(~(unsigned_type)0 >> 1)`

Comment: @programmerjake: Easier and shorter to use a suffix: `u` `ul` `ull`, pick your width.

Comment: Would `1<<(8*sizeof(x)-1)` not be more intuitive?

Comment: @programmerjake: "a signed type uses arithmetic shift right" - No it doesn't; it's implementation-defined.

Comment: You guys wanna help me out? lol I re-edited my question.

Comment: @Spellbinder2050: Take a look at programmerjake/Deduplicator's advice.

Comment: @Jongware: Or better yet, `1<<(CHAR_BIT*sizeof(x)-1)` to handle systems that don't use 8-bit `char`s.

Comment: @Adam: I've *heard* of such mythical systems. But is it stated somewhere that the unit `sizeof(x)` is "multiples of `char`s"? I.e., `sizeof(short)` on a 9-bit system is in fact `18`? (The *storage* size may be, but does it affect the bits?)

Comment: @jongware no, `sizeof(short)` is equal to `2` on 9-bit systems

Comment: @mch: sorry, I meant the size in *bits*. If it is `CHAR_BIT` times 2, then a `short` would have 18 bits, *non*? The standard may say it's *minimally* 16 bits, but surely the "extra" ones should not be used? (Where the "ones" may also be "zeroes".)

Comment: @Jongware: If `CHAR_BIT == 9` and **if** `sizeof(short) == 2`, then `short` will have 18 bits. It may have up to 2 padding bits, but there is no reason to assume that it does.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield: Or even betterer, `1U << (CHAR_BIT*sizeof(x)-1)` to handle systems that are susceptible to _undefined behaviour_. Or `1UL` or `1ULL` depending on your needs.

Answer (score 1):

`~0` is the `int` zero with all bits inverted, which is the `int` consisting of all ones.  On a 2s complement machine, this is a `-1`.  Right shifting a `-1` will cause sign extension, so `~0 >> 1` is still all ones.

What you want is to right shift an `unsigned` quantity, which will *not* invoke sign extension.

```
~0u >> 1
```

is an unsigned integer with the high order bit zero and all others set to 1, so

```
~(0u >> 1)
```

is an unsigned integer with the high order bit of one and all others set to zero.

Now getting this to work for all data sizes is nontrivial because C converts the operands of integer arithmetic to `int` or `unsigned int` beforehand.  For example,

```
~(unsigned char)0 >> 1
```

produces an `int` result of `-1` because the unsigned char is "promoted" to `int` before the `~` is applied.

So to get what you want with all data types, the only way I can see is to use `sizeof` to see how many bytes (or octets) are in the data.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#define LEADING_ONE(X)  (1 << (CHAR_BIT * sizeof(X) - 1))
int main(void) {
  printf("%x\n", LEADING_ONE(char));
  printf("%x\n", LEADING_ONE(int));
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you want to get pedantic, you should use `CHAR_BIT` instead of `8`

Comment: The result of right shifting `-1` is implementation-defined. It will _probably_ cause sign extension, but don't count on it.

Comment: I don't really understand this construct: 

LEADING_ONE(X)  (1 << (8 * sizeof(X) - 1))

It looks like a you're using a pointer to find the size of x, but I'm not too familiar with how pointers work or how to use them.

Comment: Also, I don't understand these:

LEADING_ONE(char)
LEADING_ONE(int)

Comment: @Spellbinder2050: There is no pointer involved. You pass a type name (`int`) to the macro, which applies the `sizeof` operator to compute the number of bytes in the type. Then it **multiplies** it by 8 to get the number of bits in the type (assuming 8 bits/byte). A `1` of type `signed int` is then left-shifted by the number-of-bits-minus-1 to move it into the most significant position for that type. The macro is actually incorrect for more reasons than I have room for in this comment.

Answer (score 0):

The general rule for C is that expressions are evaluated in a common type, in this case (signed) integer. The evaluation of (~0) and (~0 >> 1) are signed integers and the shift is an arithmetic shift. In your case that is being implemented with sign extension, so:

```
(0xffffffff >> 1) => (0xffffffff)
```

A logical shift will inject the zero on the left that you were expecting, so your problem is how to make the compiler do a logical shift. Try:

```
unsigned char a = ~0;
unsigned char b = a >> 1;  // this should do a logical shift
unsigned char c = ~b;
```

There are better ways to do what you are trying, but this should get you over the current problem.

Comment: The results of right-shifting a negative value is implementation-defined. It will _probably_ cause sign-extension, but don't count on it.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things that are giving you the unexpected result.

1. You are starting out with `0`, which is treated as a `signed int`.
2. The intermediate results get converted to `int`.

If you work with `unsigned char` at strategic points, you should be OK.

```
unsigned char c = ((unsigned char)~0 >> 1);
c = ~c;
```

Comment: I thought that for variable = some expression, the operands were converted to what was on the left side of the assignment symbol before the operation takes place. I'm assuming now that my idea is inaccurate?

Comment: @Spellbinder2050, that's not accurate. The RHS of the `=` gets evaluated first, independent of the LHS. If the type of value of the RHS is not the same as the type of the LHS, the RHS gets converted into the type of the LHS before the assignment happens.

Comment: @RSahu: There is no reason to assume that the RHS will be evaluated first. In a statement such as `a[i++] = a[i]`, the _LHS_ may well be evaluated _first_ which may cause some surprise for novice programmers. The order of evaluation is unrelated to the fact that the _type_ of the RHS will be converted to the _type_ of the LHS before the assignment.

Comment: Tiny nitpick: It is impossible to work _solely_ with `unsigned char`. The right shift in your answer will _still_ be performed using `signed int` (or `unsigned int` on bizarre implementations). The result will be the expected one, though (I think).